# leaflet popup when user click ouside the geojson features

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

i have made leafletjs map,i need help to set popup for :

1-geojson data (
this i have done with

> `L.geoJson(data,{style:first}).on('click',makePopup).addTo(map); )`

2-when user click outside the blue area show another popup see screenshot 
[when user click on the non blue area how can i make popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH8S8.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You have to listen to the click events on the map.

```
    var popup = L.popup();

    function onMapClick(e) {
        popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
            .openOn(mymap);
    }

    mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
```

Comment: but i have two popup one for A,and another for B how can i check if user clicked on blue area or non blue area

Comment: I guess by your screenshot that your blue area is a polygone. Look at this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ebdjrFVxlf38kyKlqLOA?p=preview

Comment: yes that works ,but it kind show the 'you clicked ....' before it shows the blue area popup